# Querying a collection of expando objects using Dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I have a collection of expando objects / dynamic as

```
var lst = new List<dynamic>();   
dynamic exp1 = new ExpandoObject();
exp1.Name = "ddd";
lst.Add(exp1);
dynamic exp2 = new ExpandoObject();
exp2.Name = "aaa";
lst.Add(exp2);
```

When I am doing

```
var query = from t in lst
where t.Name == "ddd"
select t;
```

But when I am using Dynamic Linq Library

```
var query = lst.AsQueryable().Where("Name==@0", "ddd");
```

I am getting a parse exception from dynamic linq library.

Please help me achieve this.

Comment: I thought programmers is totally different. Now I am getting confused which one is active. Please confirm

Comment: Grant Winney, Thanks for the Info

Answer (score 1):

`ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>`, so you can take advantage of that:

```
var query = from t in lst
where ((IDictionary<string, object>)t)["Name"] == "ddd"
select t;
```

Comment: Hi svick,
I am looking for Dynamic LINQ support to query the collection of expand objects. 
Besides It works directly with '.'

Comment: I assumed that you're getting `Name` as a string, which wouldn't work with `.`. If that's not the case, why would even need Dynamic LINQ?

Comment: Hi svick,
In short, I am trying to build a rules engine.

I need some possible way. Now, I am trying to use combination of Expando object and TypeDescriptionProvider, and changing the Dynamic Linq code wherever required.

Comment: I found the solution.
I implemented using my own tokeniser.